# android studio doesn't link to missing resources

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, android-resources

So I had a bunch of resources in my app I swapped them out for new resources with different names, I now need to go through my project find all the missing resources references and change them to point to the new ones, android studio used to tell you where these were, you could simply try to build the project android studio would give a bunch of errors with links, and I could select each link to take me to the errors and fix them, but after updating studio it just gives me a failed linking resources error and i have to sift through myself, I'm sure there will be another way to do this perhaps through lint, does anyone have any information on how I could achieve this quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I was right that lint checking can handle this for me analyze>inspect code> whole project and it gives me the errors with links